# Assigning to 2-D array inside a class method

Tags: c++, class

I'm can't seem to find a solution to assigning int values to a 2-d array inside a class method. Points and Dimension are set through the other functions. I could and probably should use vector here but I was wondering how I would do it the stupid way? Also for future reference I searched "C++ 2-d array inside class assign variable" but I didn't get an answer to this answer, what terminology was I missing?

```
class MatrixGraph
{
public:
    void askPoints();
    void labelPoints();
    void createMatrix();
    void defineEdges();
    void listEdges();

private:
    void findDimension();
    int points;
    string* labelArr;
    int dimension;
    int** matrix;
};
void MatrixGraph::createMatrix()
{
    findDimension();
    int** matrix = new int*[dimension];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[dimension];
    }
}
void MatrixGraph::defineEdges()
{
    int flag;
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; i < dimension; j++)
        {
            if (i != j)
            {
                cout << "Does " << i << " and " << j << " have an edge? Type 1 if it has one, 0 if not: ";
                cin >> flag;
                this->matrix[i][j] = flag;
            }
            else
            {
                this->matrix[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Better yet, use `std::vector`. As of the way it is, your class leaks memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is the `matrix` you are using `new` to allocate it is not the one you declared in your class.

Here :

```
private:
    int** matrix;
```

This `matrix` is your class member variable, But in your `createMatrix` function you are doing this :

```
int** matrix = new int*[dimension];
for(int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
{
    matrix[i] = new int[dimension];
}
```

This `matrix` is a local variable and has nothing to do with your `matrix` declared in class declaration (class member). So when you trying to use it in `defineEdges` function using `this`, it's not allocated.

So you need to change your `createMatrix` like this :

```
void MatrixGraph::createMatrix()
{
    findDimension();
    matrix = new int*[dimension];
    for (int i = 0; i < dimension; i++)
    {
        matrix[i] = new int[dimension];
    }
}
```

And keep in mind that **always** delete your allocated pointers in your class destructor to avoid memory leak. In your case, something like this :

```
~MatrixGraph()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < dimension; ++i)
    {
        delete[] matrix[i];
    }
    delete[] matrix;
    //and maybe : delete labelArr;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't catch that one...even though I removed the same mistake in another function.